# PHP SHELL EXEC WITH EXCLUDE

Tags: php, linux, shell

This is my current PHP script and it works well except that it backs up everything where in i would like to exclude the image dir.

```
<?php
function backup()
 {
  shell_exec("tar -cvf backup`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz /home/USERNAME/public_html/WEBSITE.com.au* ");
}

backup();
?>
```

THIS IS WHAT I TRYING TO DO..

```
<?php
 function backup()
 {
  shell_exec("tar --exclude /home/USERNAME/public_html/WEBSITE.com.au/images/* -cvf backup`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz /home/USERNAME/public_html/WEBSITE.com.au/");
 }

 backup();
 ?>
```

I am unable to get the exclude function to work. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just want to remove the `*` from the end of that path, since it's expanding into multiple arguments and only the first one follows `--exclude`.  You also need to drop the trailing slash, because...  I don't know.  `tar` is picky.

That said, doing this from PHP seems like a really bad idea.  Anyone who discovers this endpoint could pretty easily ramp up your CPU usage by hitting it a few times, or even corrupt your backups by hitting it in parallel.

Comment: thank i tryed <?php
function backup()
 {
  shell_exec("tar --exclude /home/www/public_html/www.com.au/images/ -cvf backup`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz /home/www/public_html/www.com.au/");
 }

backup();
?>
but it still backed up the whole thing

Comment: as for the php file it's not with in the public html folder.. this should be fine

Comment: err, how are you running it then?

Comment: edited answer; you need to drop the trailing slash too

Comment: Turns out you where right first time.. i run it as a cron job ...  oscommerce has a catalog folder and i forgot to add it... oppps sorry you where right all a long ... thankyou for your help ..

Comment: err.  if you run it as a cron job then why not just put it in a shell script?  there's no reason to involve php here.